# How to create a new form on "socket.on" event without blocking GUI?

Tags: c#, .net, socket.io

I'm new to OOP/C# and trying to create a simple chatting app. I'm done with most of the stuff thanks to the Internet and stackoverflow but I have a problem. My chat app has 2 forms, one has contact list and other one is chat interface with a person. The scenario here is; Client is on standby mode and gets a socket event that "Person x" sent him/her a message. I want to create an instance of chatting interface and pass the message to that form's textbox. Here's some code;

```
public void listener()
    {
        MainForm.SocketService.socket.On("privatemessage", (data) =>
        {
            RootObject incoming = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data.ToString());
            dict.TryGetValue(incoming.sender, out result);
            if (result != 1)
            {
                ChatScreen chatscren = new ChatScreen(incoming.sender, false, incoming.message);
                chatscren.Show();
                dict.Add(incoming.sender, 1);
            }
        });


    }
```

and I run that void in my main class;

```
public MainForm(string username)
    {
        SocketService.Init();
        listener();
    }
```

Don't mind the dictionary part, I did that in order to which forms are open Even though, I shouldn't have done that, I'd do otherway aronud If I knew how to determine which forms are open.

Problem here is; when I do that, ChatScreen form GUI freezes. I guess it's because of threads but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That requires more code to know what’s happening. Have you tried stepping through the code line by line to see where it actually hangs? What does the `ChatScreen` do when it’s shown? Or does it hang in `dinleyici`?

Comment: What socket API are you using? It doesn't look like `System.IO.Sockets` to me. (Your question is tagged with `socket-io` but that's a JavaScript library).